# Filter Array Using Partial String Match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an array of objects where the value I need to filter on is buried in a long string.  Array looks like:

```
                          {
                            "data": {
                              "value": "{\"cols\":[\"parent_sku\"],\"label\":\"Style\",\"description\":\"Enter Style.\",\"placeholderText\":\"Style 10110120103\"}",
                              "partnerId": 1
                            }
                          },
```

So if I wanted to grab all the `partnerId` objects where value includes `parent_sku` how would I do that?

`console.log(data.value.includes('parent_sku')` returns `cannot read property 'includes' of null`.

EDIT:

Didn't think this mattered, but judging by responses, seems it does.  Here's the full response object:

```
 Response body: {
                      "data": {
                        "configurationByCode": [
                          {
                            "data": {
                              "value": "{\"cols\":[\"parent_sku\"],\"label\":\"Style\",\"description\":\"Enter Style.\",\"placeholderText\":\"Style 10110120103\"}",
                              "partnerId": 1
                            }
                          }
```

I'm passing that into a re-usable function for filtering arrays:

```
const parentSkuPartners = filterArray(res.body.data.configurationByCode, 'parent_sku');
```

Function:

```
function filterArray(array, filterList) {
  const newList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    console.log('LOG', array[i].data.value.includes('parent_sku');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was some of the values for `value` were `null`.  Adding an extra conditional fixed it:

`if (array[i].data.value !== null) {`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhere else. The code you've tried should work to find if a value contains a string – I've added it the snippet below and you'll see it works.

The issue is how you are accessing `data` and `data.value`. The error message clearly states that it believes that `data.value` is null. We would need to see the code around it to be able to figure out what the problem is. Try just logging to console the value of `data` before you run the `includes` function.

```js
const data = {
  "value": "{\"cols\":[\"parent_sku\"],\"label\":\"Style\",\"description\":\"Enter Style.\",\"placeholderText\":\"Style 10110120103\"}", "partnerId": 1
};

console.log('includes?', data.value.includes('parent_sku'));
```

Comment: I've logged data.value already, that's not the issue:
`VALUE, {"cols":["parent_sku"],"label":"Style","description":"Enter Style.","placeholderText":"Style 10110120103"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.value.includes('parent_sku')` as you have suggested. The issue here is that your object is nested inside an unnamed object.

try:

```
"data": {
    "value": "{\"cols\":[\"parent_sku\"],\"label\":\"Style\",\"description\":\"Enter Style.\",\"placeholderText\":\"Style 10110120103\"}",
    "partnerId": 1
}
```

Comment: Not un-named, just didn't think it was important to understanding the issue I'm seeing, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash includes, and lodash filter like

```
let configurationByCode = [{
    data: {
        value: {
            cols:["parent_sku"],
            label:"Style",
            description:"Enter Style.",
            placeholderText:"Style 10110120103"
        },
        "partnerId": 1
    }
}, {
    data: {
        value: {
            cols:["nothing"],
            label:"Style",
            description:"Enter Style.",
            placeholderText:"Style 10110120103"
        },
        "partnerId": 2
    }
}];

let wantedData =  _.filter(configurationByCode, (config) => { 
    return _.includes(config.data.value.cols, 'parent_sku'); 
});

console.log( wantedData );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/76cndsp2/